# Why can you refresh on a hashed route on hashHistory but not on browserHistory without apiFallback?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I'm taking the react router [tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/10-clean-urls) and don't understand why in the below with hashHistory, you can refresh on a hashed route without any issues but with browserHistory you need to incorporate `--history-api-fallback`. What does that do exactly?

[image]

Why doesn't hashHistory need a fallback? How can you just go to a hashed route directly without going to the index route first? With `browserHistory`, you can't directly go to a route because it won't be able to find the files necessary to render the page, right? But how can `hashHistory` do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `hashHistory` your server only need to serve **one** url. For example, you have your site url `www.example.com` and it has `hashHistory` routing: `www.example.com/#/about`, `www.example.com/#/login`, `www.example.com/#/posts` etc. So, you have many routes, but only one url: `www.example.com`.

If you use `browserHistory` your server need to serve multiple urls (according to your app routes amount). For example you have `www.example.com/`, `www.example.com/about`, `www.example.com/login`, `www.example.com/posts` - then you can configure your server so it will give your app assets for `www.example.com/` url. And for all other urls (`/about`,`/login`, `/posts` etc) it can fallback to `www.example.com/` (and give client the same assets). If you won't enable a fallback for other urls you will get page not found errors (or 404 errors for your assets).